# I am trying to set different markers to an array of addresses. I want a separate infowindow for each. I am not getting infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, infowindow, marker

I am calling a function from PHP(being called successfully) and trying to set infowindows for each of  the markers. the markers are being set, however infowindow is not being set for each marker.

The code for the same is below.

```
var markers = [];
var infowin = [];

function addMarker(address, name, contact, id, x) {
  switch(x) {
    case "domestic":
      icon = "grn-blank";
      break;
    case "plumber":
      icon = "purple-blank";
      break;
    case "laundry":
      icon = "orange-blank";
      break;
    case "carpenter":
      icon = "red-blank";
      break;
    case "milk_vendor":
      icon = "ylw-blank";
      break;
    case "electrician":
      icon = "pink-blank";
      break;
    case "newspaper_vendor":
      icon = "blu-blank";
      break;
  }
  var iconbase = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/";
  var icon = icon + ".png";
  var icons = iconbase + icon ;

  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage(icons)
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });

  var contentw = "Name: " + name + "\nAddress: " + address + " \nPhone: " + contact + "\nId-Number: " + id;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentw
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  infowin.push(infowindow); 
}
```

What implementation can I do to avoid this problem?

Comment: One way to solve your issue is with [function closure on the geocode operation and the create marker operation](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1210329+geocoder+infowindows+function+closure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition in your code. To understand it, have a look at the following stripped-down example.

```
function addMarker(...) {
  ...
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      // This is where you create the marker (in an asynchronous callback)
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ ... });
      ...
    }
  });
  ...
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ ... });

  // This is where you access the marker (in the surrounding function)
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  ...
}
```

The geocoding request is made asynchronously. Hence, by the time the callback `function(results, status)` is executed, the surrounding `addMarker` function will probably already have finished executing. The race condition occurs at the end of `addMarker` when you try to access the `marker` variable. The value of this variable will, however, not be assigned before the geocoding callback has executed.

To resolve this issue, all you need to do is move the info window code into the geocoding callback.

```
function addMarker(...) {
  ...
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ ... });
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ ... });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      ...
    }
  });
  ...
}
```

Check out a working example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/612wsjst/2/).

Comment: Wowwwww!!! Thank you so much! It actually worked. Now I am getting only one small problem. I am getting infowindow only for one marker(probably the last marker that I set. If you can guess what might be the problem then please let me know otherwise this will be fine too. Thanks again!!

Comment: @gaurav95 You're welcome but don't forget to mark the accepted answer. ;) That other problem is probably worth a separate Stackoverflow question as it's hard to analyse it without the source code.